# Ubuntu15.04 install itorch error: Missing dependencies for itorch: luacrypto uuid lzmq >= 0.4.2

Tags: ubuntu-15.04

I am installing itorch according to https://github.com/facebook/iTorch, and I have installed ipython. Some errors are as followed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libzmq3-dev is already the newest version.

lei@lei-All-Series:~/torch/iTorch$ sudo env "PATH=$PATH" luarocks make

Missing dependencies for itorch:
luacrypto 
uuid 
lzmq >= 0.4.2

Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocks-moonscript-org/moonrocks-mirror/master/luacrypto-0.3.2-1.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocks-moonscript-org/moonrocks-mirror/master/luacrypto-0.3.2-1.src.rock - Could not find expected file openssl/evp.h, or openssl/evp.h for OPENSSL -- you may have to install OPENSSL in your system and/or pass OPENSSL_DIR or OPENSSL_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install luacrypto OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local

lei@lei-All-Series:~/torch/iTorch$ luarocks make

Missing dependencies for itorch:
luacrypto 
uuid 
lzmq >= 0.4.2

Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocks-moonscript-org/moonrocks-mirror/master/luacrypto-0.3.2-1.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocks-moonscript-org/moonrocks-mirror/master/luacrypto-0.3.2-1.src.rock - Could not find expected file openssl/evp.h, or openssl/evp.h for OPENSSL -- you may have to install OPENSSL in your system and/or pass OPENSSL_DIR or OPENSSL_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install luacrypto OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local
```

Comment: This might be a better question for SuperUser (which is another StackExchange Q&A site). According to the error, It looks like OpenSSL is not installed on your machine

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I have installed openssl. I don't know how to solve this problem.                                                                     lei@lei-All-Series:~$ sudo apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version.
openssl set to manually installed.

Comment: I solve it! Just re-install Torch and CUDA.

Comment: Anyone else have this problem?  I do have openssl installed and this error still occurs for me.  Reinstalling torch did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev. It surely works